# Can't update a table with a trigger

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, sql-update

I'm using PostGreSQL, i've this schema :

- BASEWORKS(id, tsv, ....)
- WORKS(id, ....)

I want to update Baseworks when Works is updated, with a trigger

```
create or replace function works_vector_update() returns trigger as $$ 
begin 
    update baseworks 
    set tsv =  'THIS IS A TEST' 
    where id =  new.id;
    RAISE NOTICE 'i m passing here';
    return null;
end 
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

and the trigger :

```
create trigger tsvectorworksupdate after insert or update on works 
for each row execute procedure works_vector_update();
```

all is fine when i insert or update Works table, i raise the notice  but the field baseworks.tsv is never updated and i can't understand why ...

Comment: My suspicion would be this: `where id =  new.id; ` Does `baseworks` have a row  with `id` that equals `new.id`?

Comment: Yes i've the same id in both table. In fact the problem seem's to be on the line above. ````set tsv= 'THIS IS A TEST'```` is in fact ```set tsv=to_tsvector(concat_ws(' ', 'TEST'))``` and the problem seems to be here when i try to update this tsvector column ...

Comment: The good question is how to update a tsvector column on TABLE1 when an event append on TABLE2 (insert or update) ...

Comment: Update  the code in your question with the actual statement used. Also update question to include complete table definitions for `baseworks` and `works` with field names and field types. Finally, have you looked at the Postgres log to see if there is useful information?

Comment: Another thought, are the tables names `BASEWORKS` and `WORKS` or `baseworks` and `works`?